# Firebase Storage fails to update cross-service rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

When deploying storage security rules in Firebase, I get this:

```
i  deploying storage
i  storage: ensuring required API firebasestorage.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  storage: required API firebasestorage.googleapis.com is enabled
i  firebase.storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
✔  firebase.storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
? Cloud Storage for Firebase needs an IAM Role to use cross-service rules. Grant the new role? Yes
[rules] Error checking or updating Cloud Storage for Firebase service account permissions.
[rules] Cross-service Storage rules may not function properly HTTP Error: 400, Service account service-927044470795@gcp-sa-firebasestorage.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not exist.
```

I also get a warning about missing permissions in the Firebase Console, but when I click the button to fix it, it generates an error.  I'm not able to create a service account with the indicated name.

Comment: If you're seeing an unexpected error with the Firebase console, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) and explain what's not working the way you expect.